# strange duplicate on group

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What can be wrong ? Any help is appreciated.

```
@entries = Entry.where(:created_at => 3.day.ago.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day).group("date(created_at)").select("created_at, count(id) as tcount")

<% @entries.each_with_index do |entry, index| %>
<%= entry.created_at.strftime("%d/%m") %>
<% end %>
```

Output:

```
16/07
16/07
18/07
19/07
```

Comment: it's possible to have two record created on the same day.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt understand. Can u give me example  please?

Comment: `16/07` is a date. You can have multiple entires with the same date.

Comment: I grouped entries by created_at, how come i see duplicated group name?

Comment: Why the down vote?  That was actually a good, tricky problem!

Comment: @Codeglot of course it has multiple records created on the same day, that's why he's grouping and counting, to find the number of records created each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select the records, it is grouping by the database's date() function, which uses what is actually stored in the database, but you are selecting the complete created_at, including time.  It chooses the first one as the value.  Timezone conversions are then coming into play when you actually display it.  I bet one of those 16's should be a 15.

Try:

```
@entries = Entry.where(:created_at => 3.day.ago.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day).group("date(created_at)").select("date(created_at) as date, count(id) as tcount")

<% @entries.each_with_index do |entry, index| %>
<%= entry.date.strftime("%d/%m") %>
<% end %>
```